# My laptop toshiba satellite p75-A7100 pad right-click is working as a left-click?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

My laptop Toshiba satellite p75-A7100 pad right-click is working as a left-click in Ubuntu after updating to 18.04 Ubuntu? I've seen other answers but they are not working for me!

Comment: What other answers have you tried? Please edit your question to provide more information

Comment: In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? If so, what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Open **settings**, click on **Devices** and open the **Mouse & Touchpad** tab.
You will get a window similar to the one above.
Change the **Primary Button** to **Left**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but it is already left  clicked. :)